# How to differentiate between horizontal scale, horizontal drag with one finger, horizontal drag with two fingers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, gesture, gesturedetector

I am doing a more complex custom chart requiring special treatment of three main actions:

- user is scaling the widget horizontally (one finger going left, other finger going right)
- user is dragging with one finger to the left or to the right
- user is dragging with two fingers to the left or to the right.

[image: Gestures]

I tried using this code (and many other variations, but this seems to be the closest to the required behaviour):

````dart
class ChartGestureDetector extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(Offset localStartPosition, double delta) onDragWithOneFinger;
  final void Function(Offset localStartPosition, double delta) onDragWithTwoFingers;
  final void Function(Offset localStartPosition, double scale) onScale;
  final Widget child;

  ChartGestureDetector({
    required this.onDragWithOneFinger,
    required this.onDragWithTwoFingers,
    required this.onScale,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onScaleStart: (details) {
        // Handle scale start if needed
      },
      onScaleUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.scale != 1.0) {
          // Two-finger gesture (scale)
          onScale(details.localFocalPoint, details.scale);
        } else if (details.pointerCount == 1) {
          // One-finger gesture (pan)
          onDragWithOneFinger(details.localFocalPoint, details.horizontalScale);
        } else if (details.pointerCount == 2) {
          // Two-finger gesture (pan)
          onDragWithTwoFingers(details.localFocalPoint, details.horizontalScale);
        }
      },
      onScaleEnd: (details) {
        // Handle scale end if needed
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}```

Full demo here: https://pastebin.com/GNkHQ3k2


But it counts two finger drag as a scale.
How do I fix this code or what other approach should I take?
Is there any package that does what I am trying to do easier?
````

Comment: so change `details.scale != 1` to something `details.scale < 0.9 || details.scale > 1.1` or similar stuff

Comment: of course you have to play with those numbers, maybe not `1.1` but `1.05` or `1.01`

Comment: It mostly work, thank you!

Comment: mostly? what does not? btw you should actually use some `const scale = 1.05`, and `details.scale < 1/scale || details.scale > scale`

Comment: It confuses a drag with two fingers with scale sometimes but I hope it doesn't matter too much when implementing the actual application. I will tinker with the values a little bit, ignore the gesture if verticalScale is outside a given range and hope it will work fine in the end.

Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, your welcome